# A question about pairwise mutual exclusive events

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

There is a common problem in the field of probability as follows:

"On a vessel containing 3 white and 5 black balls, 4 balls are transferred into an empty vessel. From this vessel a ball is drawn and it is found to be white. What is the probability that out of 4 balls transferred 3 are white and 1 is black?"

The solution is given on page 335 of the book "Engineering Mathematics by Sarveswara Rao Koneru (Universities Press, 2002)" as follows:

"The four balls transferred can be only one of the following combinations:

Event $A_1$ : 4B + 0W

Event $A_2$ : 3B + 1W

Event $A_3$ : 2B + 2W

Event $A_4$ : 1B + 3W

$A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$ are pairwise mutual exclusive since just one of them must happen so if E is the event of choosing a white ball from the second vessel,

$E = EA_1 \cup EA_2 \cup EA_3 \cup EA_4$

(and the answer continues to the end...)"

My question is how does the above equation hold and how does the author concluded that?

Comment: Hard to answer because it is unclear what you are asking.  In general, if events $B_1, \cdots, B_n$ are pairwise mutually exclusive, then the probabiltiy that one of the events $B_1, \cdots, B_n$ occurred is $[p(B_1) + \cdots + p(B_n)].$  In the given problem, since events $A_1, \cdots, A_4$ are pairwise mutually exclusive, so are the events $(EA_1), \cdots, (EA_4)$.

Comment: Continuing, in the given problem, since one of $A_1, \cdots, A_4$ must have occurred, $p(A_1) + \cdots + p(A_4) = 1.$  Given that event $E$ occurred, it must have been coupled with exactly one of $A_1, \cdots, A_4$.  Therefore, $p(E) = p(EA_1) + \cdots + p(EA_4).$

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks,. I think in your second comment I got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\}$ are not just pairwise mutually exclusive events, they are also exhaustive.  This is a set of events which *partitions* the outcome set.

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all possible outcomes for drawing four balls from the vessel.   Since any outcome must be in one among the events from $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\}$, then $\Omega=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4$.   Thus they are exhaustive over $\Omega$.

This exhaustive property is what is used to claim:

$$\begin{align}E&=E\cap\Omega\\&=E\cap(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4)\\&=(E\cap A_1)\cup(E\cap A_2)\cup(E\cap A_3)\cup(E\cap A_4)\end{align}$$

---

Mutual exclusivity comes next.

Since any event in $E$, is an event in $\Omega$, it  must be in *exactly one* among the events from $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\}$, and therefore in *exactly one* among the events from $\{(E\cap A_1),(E\cap A_2),(E\cap A_3),(E\cap A_4)\}$.  Therefore this later set of events is *also* pairwise mutually exclusive.   The probability of a union of pairwise mutually exclusive events equals the sum of the probabilities of those events.

As we have already shown that this union equals $E$, thus:
$$\mathsf P(E)=\mathsf P(E\cap A_1)+\mathsf P(E\cap A_2)+\mathsf P(E\cap A_3)+\mathsf P(E\cap A_4)$$

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant explanation.